# Ошибка при запуске Error:Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for 19 (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблемму с ошибкой [image: JDK 19 установлен...]

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение: Версия IDEA просто не поддерживает JDK 19, исправил тем что скачал более свежую версию...